# How to encrypt an decrypt url in php

Tags: php, encryption

Passing 1000 of array variables through url and getting it back in another page.how can i encrypt url which is dynamically creating and de crypt back to original stage for further querying.
my url is look like this :

http://example.com/abc/abc1.php?808=880&807=879&806=878&805=877&804=876&803=875&802=872&801=871&800=869&799=868&798=867&797=866&796=865&795=864&794=863&793=862&792=861&791=860&790=859&789=858&788=857&787=856&786=855&785=854&784=853&783=852&782=850&781=849&780=848&779=847&778=846&777=845&776=844&775=843&774=842&773=841&772=840

Code:

```
$rfinalarray = array_intersect($rarray1, $rarray2, $rarray3, $rarray4, $rarray5, $rarray6, $rarray7, $rarray8, $rarray9, $rarray10, $rarray12, $rarray13, $rarray14, $rarray15, $rarray16, $rarray17);
if (count($rfinalarray) > 0) {
    $arrayr = array_values($rfinalarray);
    arsort($arrayr);
    $ab = http_build_query($arrayr);

    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: http://example.com/abc.php?$ab");
} else {
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: http://example.com/abc.php?search=noresult");
    unset($_SESSION['reals']);
}
```

Comment: Have HTTPS do it for you.

Comment: Use post instead. Not a good approach.

Comment: There's a limit to how many characters you can have in a URL bar. If you have `"1000 of array variables"`, then you'll be losing some through the redirect.

Comment: I wonder what sort of problem might couse you to send array with length of 1000 using any request method. Maybe you are approaching it from wrong angle, such solutions most often backfire.

Comment: Post?To pass data to another page....?Actually am trying to change the code that some one written.They pass the search result stored in array through url.here when data is too much its going to internal server error.So please suggest me the way to this search efficiently

Answer (score 1):

This is not good approach using GET, use POST instead. But for you information, try with this:

```
<?php
function encrypt_url($string) {
  $key = "MAL_979805"; //key to encrypt and decrypts.
  $result = '';
  $test = "";
   for($i=0; $i<strlen($string); $i++) {
     $char = substr($string, $i, 1);
     $keychar = substr($key, ($i % strlen($key))-1, 1);
     $char = chr(ord($char)+ord($keychar));

     $test[$char]= ord($char)+ord($keychar);
     $result.=$char;
   }

   return urlencode(base64_encode($result));
}

function decrypt_url($string) {
    $key = "MAL_979805"; //key to encrypt and decrypts.
    $result = '';
    $string = base64_decode(urldecode($string));
   for($i=0; $i<strlen($string); $i++) {
     $char = substr($string, $i, 1);
     $keychar = substr($key, ($i % strlen($key))-1, 1);
     $char = chr(ord($char)-ord($keychar));
     $result.=$char;
   }
   return $result;
}
?>
```

Took from [here](http://www.zimplicit.se/en/knowledge/how-encrypt-and-decrypt-url-when-using-get)

Comment: A Caesar cipher is not very secure. It's better to use some modern ciphers like AES through `openssl_encrypt` or libsodium.

Answer (score 0):

Updated approach saving data in hidden form and submitting the form on dom ready, onthe contrary the form could be submitted on an event too.

At ab.php

```
$array = serialize($ab);
<form action="ac.php" method="post" id="test">
     <textarea name="array" style="display:none;">
          <?php echo $array;?>
     </textarea>
</form>
```

Using jquery at ab.php :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form#test').submit();
});
```

@ ac.php you can get it via $_POST
Hope that helps

Comment: Hi akash...                                                                                                        $.ajax({
    url: "abc/ab.php", // script to handle the post data
    type : "POST",
    data : "mypostdata=<?php echo serialize('$ab'); ?>",
    success : function(response){ // json encoded response to show    success
    if(response.success == true)
    {
         window.location = "http://example.com/ad/abc/ac.php";
    }
}
});
i want to display the result in ac.php.So is this correct.Doesn't work for me

Comment: Encoding/serialization is no encryption.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/emmnL74R                                                                    Please see my query and tell me where am wrong...

Comment: Can i use session to get this array?

Comment: @ArtjomB. am **NOT** encoding the url data it's another approach please read the description

Comment: You're hiding the data in the POST body through the use of PHP's serialize which serializes an array into a string. It's a form of encoding and has nothing to do with encryption. Furthermore, this is wrong, because the serialize result may contain binary data which may break the representation in JavaScript and may send wrong values.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I think you get the overall idea wrong. My point was to **NOT ENCODE** anything at all, because encoded url data **just** to get data just feels wrong, what alley is looking for is just to submit data from one page ab.php to page ac.php, but he is doing it via GET which is wrong. 

**There was no mention of binary data anywhere** not even the example posted in the question. Make sense ?

Comment: @Alley I have updated my answer to more simpler approach. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you akashBhardwaj...Thanks for your effort and time.

Comment: @Alley Most welcome. Does that help ?

Comment: I didn't try it.I use session to store that variable like $_SESSION['reals']=$ab; and call the session in next page.This is working for me.Is this having any drawbacks? I will try your code and acknowledge you and most thankful to you for helping me.